# Error in pgfcorearrows.code.tex file

Tags: compilation-error, pgf-core

Forgive me if the title that I've given to this post isn't appropriate. I am just an average latex user who knows how to write few basic latex codes, and don't know much about the technicalities.

BACKGROUND STORY: last night I was trying to structure my manuscript according as the Springer Nature's latex template. Basically, I collected the said template from one of my seniors as a zip file. I extracted the tex and class files and put them in a folder where I usually keep my all tex files. I ran the springer nature sample tex file and it did compile and ran (although there were few warnings!). Then I created a separate tex file and copied the contents of the sample tex file in it. After that I started to paste my manuscript's contents into the same. Once done I tried to run the same, but I am getting the following error message during compilation ever since:

```
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Missing \begin{document}. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Missing number, treated as zero. }
line 1061: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
line 1061: Extra \else. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Missing number, treated as zero. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 1061: Undefined control sequence. }
line 27: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1073. \input pgfcorearrows.code.tex
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@iinput has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@iinput was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }. \input
line 28: Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete. \input
line 28: Missing \endcsname inserted. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 28: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \input
line 841: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <16> not available(Font) size <17.28> substituted
line 841: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <16> not available(Font) size <17.28> substituted
line 841: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <16> not available(Font) size <17.28> substituted
line 841: Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <16> not available(Font) size <17.28> substituted
: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
```

The following is the list of packages that I've included on my own:

```
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

I haven't encountered such an error message before, and also if I click on any of the mentioned line numbers the file "pgfcorearrows.code.tex" opens up out of nowhere! I don't really know what it is. Moreover, since last night my manuscript which used to run even without a single warning is not running, rather showing the same error messages. Only the springer nature's original tex file is running although with two warnings:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 22.3)
The top-level auxiliary file: sn-article.aux
I couldn't open style file sn-mathphys.bst
---line 3 of file sn-article.aux
 : \bibstyle{sn-mathphys
 :                      }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file sn-article.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

I'm confused. So, it would be really helpful for me if someone tells me what exactly I'm doing wrong, or how I could actually resolve this issue.

Comment: From the duplicate: add ``\catcode`\|=12\relax`` after `\documentclass{sn-jnl}` to fix the issue. Note that the Springer class already loads `amsmath` and `graphicx`, so you don't need to load them yourself. `epstopdf` is not needed anymore (for the last 10 years or so) so you can remove that too, `graphicx` automatically converts eps figures to pdf when needed.

Comment: @Marjin, First of all thank you sir. Sir, I went through the link, and as suggested I've added `\usepackage{program}` and `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` with `\catcode`\|=12\relax` in between. But getting the same error messages. I clicked on the first error message it took me to the following section: `\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = _,
  defaults = {sep},
  drawing code =
}`   of the pgfcorearrows.code.tex file.

Comment: Admittedly the answers in the duplicate are not very clear. What you need to do is ``\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}\catcode`\|=12\relax\usepackage{tikz-cd}\jyear{2022}...theorem declarations if needed...\begin{document}``.

Comment: of course you can change `sn-mathphys` to the journal name that you need to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. The same annoying error messages keep popping up!

Comment: There could be more characters that are messed up by the `program` package that is loaded by the Springer class, maybe you can reset them too. Does this happen on the sample tex file from Springer with just the `tikz-cd` package added (and the catcode fix for `|` applied), or do you get the errors only on your full manuscript with actual `tikz-cd` code?

Comment: @Marijn, _maybe you can reset them too_ -No sir, I do not know how to manipulate a class file! _Does this happen on the sample tex file from Springer with just the tikz-cd package added (and the catcode fix for `|` applied),_ -Yes, I just tried to add the package `tikz-cd` to the original sample tex file, and got the same error messages. Without the said package the original sample tex file does run. However, none of my previous tex files are being compiled since last night.